# Set scope input value not working

Tags: angularjs

HTML

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="connector_form.a" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"  placeholder="{productname}">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.connector_form.a = "test;
```

Not working for me.

When changing it to:

HTML

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="connector_form" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"  placeholder="{productname}">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.connector_form = "test;
```

It works.

Probably a newbie question but I can't find the answer.

Comment: angularjs + bootstrap when there is angular-materials out there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have an empty object

```
$scope.connector_form = {};
```

and then

```
$scope.connector_form.a = "test;
```

otherwise **`$scope.connector_form`** will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS will create a property from an `ng-model` directive, but only by adding it to an existing object.

If `$scope.connector_form` does not exist then it is unable to attach the `a` property. So you must declare `$scope.connector_form` somewhere in your controller.

```
angular.module('appModule', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.connector_form = {};
});
```

Or, to set an initial value:

```
angular.module('appModule', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.connector_form = {
        a: 'default value';
    };
});
```